# How to shorten the url to just the action parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

If a website with url "www.site.com", redirects to HomeController's Index action.

I have

```
www.site.com/area/controller/action/{nick}
```

I want the url

```
www.site.com/{nick}
```

do the same thing

How I do to create a route and where do I have to create it?

In the RouteConfig.cs or in the AreaRegistration.cs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `RouteConfig.cs`, add following route after all routes.

```
routes.MapRoute
(
    name: "Nick Route",
    url: "{nick}",
    defaults: new { area = "AreaName",
                    controller = "controllerName",
                    action = "Actionname",
                    nick = UrlParameter.Optional  });
```

Comment: Probably best to add this *after* the default.

Comment: Hello @Bhushan Firake ,I don't have any file named routeConfig.cs in my project so where should I change this?

Comment: @padhiyar You might not have this file but you will still have the same configuration in Global.asax file. sorry for the late reply..

Comment: Yes @BhushanFirake I got the file and it is running perfectly fine using Diksito's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this post is old but if someone is interested, he may find the solution here http://www.nikolay-angelov.eu/custom-url-shortener-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "URL",
            url: "{shortURL}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "RedirectToLong", shortUrl = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Basic",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```